# Dynamically generate Javascript with JSP in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jsp

I try to do something like that
**1.**

```
<head><% out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">"); out.println("function myfunction(){"); out.println("for(int i=0;i<10;i++){"); out.println("alert(message+i);"); out.println("}}"); out.println("</script></head>"); %>
```

and use it like that

```
<body><input type="button" value="abcd" onclick="myfunction();"/></body>
```

That is generate javascript within my jsp Pages.And it works fine but only in chrome and not in IE.I then tried this **2.**

```
<head><%StringBuffer dynamicJavaScript = new StringBuffer();dynamicJavaScript.append("\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">");dynamicJavaScript.append("\n</script>");%></head>
```

and use it like that again inside the  tag

```
<%=dynamicJavaScript%>
```

In a weird way only  if i include **both** of these solutions **(1. & 2.)** it works in IE.
Have yoy got any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> function my function(){
> ```

This is syntactically invalid in two ways: 1) `my` is wrong here. 2) `function` is a reserved keyword.

With regard to generating Javascript code dynamically, I strongly recommend you to **not** use *scriptlets* for this, but just taglibs/EL. Your first line can be perfectly replaced with help of [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) (just drop [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`) [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html):

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
            // <c:forEach begin="0" end="10" var="i">
                alert(message${i});
            // </c:forEach>
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Much better readable, isn't it?

**Update** as per the comments, you can also iterate over a `Collection` with `c:forEach`. Replace the particular piece by:

```
            <c:forEach items="${bean.vector}" var="item">
                alert('${item}');
            </c:forEach>
```

..where `${bean}` is your bean which is been placed in any of the `page`, `request`, `session` or `application` scopes and `${bean.vector}` requires having a getter with that name in the `Bean` class like

```
public class Bean {
    public Vector<String> getVector() {
        return this.vector;
    }
}
```

To learn more about JSTL, consult Sun [Java EE tutorial part II chapter 7](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html). To learn more about EL, consult [Java EE tutorial part II chapter 5](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html).

That said, the `Vector` is considered *legacy* and you should be using the improved [`ArrayList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead which has already replaced it over a decade ago (more about Collections framework in [this Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html)). In this line, I would also recommend to throw all those >10 year old tutorials/books away and go read the more recent ones.

Comment: I must say i'm not so good with EL.I want to get a Vector from a bean first and then generate a javascript with a for loop that shows the elements of the Vector.The problem is i don't know how to get the vector with EL.Something like that...
Vector<generic> myVector = mybean.getMyVector();
for (int i = 1; i < myVector .getSize(); i++) {
out.println("alert("+myVector.elementAt(i).getMyProperty()+");");
}

Comment: I programmed it exactly as you suggested but i still have the initial problem.In chrome all is working fine but in IE i get an error "object expected" which means that IE can't see myFunction().Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org) based on the **generated HTML output** (the JSP code is irrelevant here).